# offline Bin Packing problem with multiple size bins

Tags: algorithms, optimization, packing

As per my research on stack overflow communities, This is probably known as cutting stock problem / multiple Knapsack problem (a variant of the bin packing problem) which is NP hard.

here are the constraints:

- there are two integer arrays one has lengths (already defined), the other has
  the bin sizes (already defined),
- lengths needs to be packed in any combination of bin of any size, the desired solution would be with least wastage of total bin used
  bins but off course but collective wastage of all the used bin must be least
- the lengths and bin sizes are fixed and will be provided by another process before computation start

based on First Fit Decreasing (FFD) algorithm i am able to pack bin of a fixed size but the wastage is not minimum. Refer to the results in images achieved so far... One can get optimum results when mix size bins are used. What would be the algorithm in case of multiple bin utilized ?

**Data:**

```
Lengths: {2385,2385,2385,2385,2385,2385,1260,1260,1260,1260,1260,1260,337,337,210,210,125,125,108,108}
Bins: {3000,5000}
```

**Results based on FFD algorithm of bin packing**

When i use bin length of 3000 only the total wastage is 3434
[image: Bin size 3000 wastage 3434]

When i use bin length of 5000 only the total wastage is 1570
[image: Bin size 5000 wastage 1570]

When mix length bins (3000 and 5000) are used the total wastage is 570, the problem is what would be an
optimum algorithm to achieve this or even better than this ?
[image: Bin size MULTIPLE wastage 570]

Comment: Are you looking for the algorithm finding the optimal solution or just a better approximation algorithm?
As you already mentioned the problem is NP-hard so there isn't any known feasible algorithm for the optimal solution (for a big number of bins and items). It seems you apply your algo in a real life scenario - what are the bounds on the number of bins and number of items?

Comment: Im looking for a better approximation algorithm, which can give me least waste space.
as i mentioned for single size bin i use First Fit Decreasing algorithm, but problem arises when multiple size bins are available.
i mentioned its a NP-hard problem based on my research on stack overflow and google... 
Real life scenario is aluminum length cutting for different size door extrusions from fixed size stock lengths.
The bounds (if matter) are: No of bins (stock lengths) can be 1-5 while lengths (cuts) can be 1-50, all measurements are in integers and available in advance for computations...

Comment: the images depict just an example scenario...